# Connect linux computers to CentOS websever

Tags: linux, wordpress, virtualbox

i would like to ask on how other linux computer can connect to my CentOS web Server.Btw, I'm using virtual box on those CentOS. I tried googling it but i giving me hard time to find a good answer, so im trying to ask here if someone knows about it. Advance thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are trying to access the web server.

If you are simply trying to access a website you have on the server, then you have the following options:

- If the ip address of the server is registered with DNS then it's pretty much straightforward.
- If the ip address is not registered, etc. and it's under the same network as the other linux computer then you need to know what ip address the CentOS web server has which you will use to access via a web browser.
- If the web server is located in another network, then you will have to look into port forwarding.

If you  are trying to access the web server to do anything else but accessing a website (e.g. installing software, doing configuration, etc.) then you have the following option(s):

- setup SSH to securely access the server remotely.